# Where does the decoy run in Assassin's Creed 1?

Tags: assassins-creed

In one of the later missions in Assassin's Creed 1, you are told to assassinate a dude.

> This takes place during the Robert de Sable assassination mission, during the funeral (thanks utkuerd!).  When you reach your target, you discover that it's not actually your target, but a decoy.  After interrogating her, you let her go, and she runs off.  I was playing a particularly violent, "No one sees my face and lives" sort of Altair, and the first thing I did was chase after her to try to catch and kill her.  Luckily for her, she lost me about halfway through the city when I bumped into a soldier and went into combat mode.  I never found her again.

**Where does the decoy run, and can the decoy be killed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altaïr does not kill her, so you can't choose to do so. Her fate will be explained in *Assassin's Creed: Revelations* in the Altaïr memories.

Answer (score 2):

I presume this was the Robert de Sablé assassination. In the plot you spare the life of decoy in this assassination and you should return to bureau for further progress. (The decoy even has a role in later games.)

However most probably you can kill her if you try, but she won't turn back and fight. She will just flee, so it will be a little hard.

Comment: That's correct, it was the Robert de Sable mission.  I'll edit my question to make that information more clear.

Comment: I chased her for a LONG time, but she's actually super fast.  I think she just disappears when out of sight.

Answer (score -2):

There is no reason to do so (unless you have a thing against decoy women) but if you are interested in her story play Assassin's Creed Revelations!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Can you kill the decoy or not is what he's asking.